# Using ggplot to plot multiple lines grouped by date in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following test data:

```
Date <- c('2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-04-04' , '2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' , '2022-05-02' , '2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02')
Trt <- c('A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E')
mean <- c('7' , '5' , '7' , '5' , '7' , '9' , '7' , '8' , '6' , '9' , '13' , '10' , '12' , '8' , '12') 
sd    <- c('2' , '1' , '2' , '1' , '1' , '2' , '2' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '2' , '2' , '2')

data <- data.frame(Date , Trt , mean , sd)
```

I'd like to plot this where each of the three dates is a point on the x axis, the y axis is the means, and each of the five trts is a different color line with its corresponding mean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these options:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

Date <- c('2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-03-07' , '2022-04-04' , '2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' ,'2022-04-04' , '2022-05-02' , '2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02' ,'2022-05-02')
Trt <- c('A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E')
mean <- c('7' , '5' , '7' , '5' , '7' , '9' , '7' , '8' , '6' , '9' , '13' , '10' , '12' , '8' , '12') 
sd    <- c('2' , '1' , '2' , '1' , '1' , '2' , '2' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '1' , '2' , '2' , '2')

data <- data.frame(Date , Trt , mean , sd)

# Some points overplot
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(Date, mean, colour = Trt)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
# So you could jitter them a little
data|> 
  ggplot(aes(Date, mean, colour = Trt)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.01)
```

[image]

```r
# If you want to convert the dates from character to date
data|> 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Date, mean, colour = Trt)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.01)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>